# How do I execute a PHP function for every line in standard input?

Tags: php, web-scraping, garbage-collection, filehandle

With some background in Linux I have come accustomed to these so called [oneliners](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt). Today I want to convert some HTML-garbage (entities) to plain text with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) from core PHP.

e.g.

```
>> html_entity_decode( '&gt;' )
'>'
```

According to the help of the interpreter, this can be done with the `-R` option;

> Usage: php [options] [-f]  [--] [args...] 
>   (...)
>     -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
>   (...)

However, often when I think that PHP is great, it gives me reason to think otherwise (pardon the attitude);

```
seq 10  | php -R 'echo fgets(STDIN);'
2
4
6
8
10
```

...as the case often is, stating the problem often leads to a solution. So I figured out the problem while writing this question. The standard in is closed because PHP closes open file handles upon termination (see [freeing resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)) and that throws away every second line due to some *!enticing* implementation detail.

Thanks for reading, you can always golf my solution if you like...

---

The part about closing file handles automatically is inferred because *variables go out of scope* as the *main is popped from the execution stack*. I have yet to find this documented on php.net.

Comment: No idea what you are asking

Comment: @Dagon I could rephrase/translate in leet-speak?

Comment: I would settle for English

Comment: Now now, don't be rude.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the standard in open, read all lines with one script (iirc as you would in a similar Perl oneliner);

```
wget https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories -O- |
    html2text -nobs -style pretty -width 120  |
    php -r 'while ($ii = fgets(STDIN))
                echo html_entity_decode($ii);'
```

[Hooray!](http://www.elftor.com/elftor.php?number=124)